# The residuals vs fitted values plot of ARIMA model in r

Tags: r

I fitted an ARIMA model like follows:

```
arima_pri <- Arima(prits, order=c(7,1,0), xreg = t2, seasonal=list(order=c(1,1,1), period=12))
```

And want to look at the residuals vs fitted values plot:

```
plot(fitted(arima_pri), arima_pri$residuals)
```

then got this[image]

Also tried ts.plot:

```
ts.plot(fitted(arima_pri), arima_pri$residuals)
```

then got this[image]

It's still weird! I want to get a plot like[image]

See http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/21465_653278de4ce44fefa846002156e9b10a.html

Or,

[image]

(See http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/21465_653278de4ce44fefa846002156e9b10a.html)

I'm sure all the libraries have been loaded correctly like "forecast". What should I do now? Thank you!

Comment: Which libraries are you using? The error may be on the residuals part. which residual type are you using? try `sum(resid(arima_pri));sum(arima_pri$resid)` and even change the residual type and check wether they are equa

Comment: @Onyambu I'm using "tseries" and "forecast", and the two sums are exactly the same :(